# Define a python dictionary with immutable keys but mutable values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, immutability

Well, the question is in the title: how do I define a python dictionary with immutable keys but mutable values? I came up with this (in python 2.x):

```
class FixedDict(dict):
    """
    A dictionary with a fixed set of keys
    """

    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        dict.__init__(self)
        for key in dictionary.keys():
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, dictionary[key])

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if key not in self:
            raise KeyError("The key '" +key+"' is not defined")
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, item)
```

but it looks to me (unsurprisingly) rather sloppy. In particular, is this safe or is there the risk of actually changing/adding some keys, since I'm inheriting from dict?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, someone could presumably call `dict.__setitem__()` on an instance of `FixedDict`, no?

Comment: You should check to make sure that `dict.update` calls `__setitem__` -- Although, even if it does, I'm not sure whether or not that is implementation dependent ...

Comment: (`update` bypasses `__setitem__`)

Comment: The implementation of (almost?) all C built-ins bypasses python's methods, to avoid subclasses breaking them.

Comment: "To avoid subclasses breaking them"?  It's the bypassing that makes subclasses break them.  They bypass `__setitem__` for speed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider proxying `dict` instead of subclassing it. That means that only the methods that you define will be allowed, instead of falling back to `dict`'s implementations.

```
class FixedDict(object):
        def __init__(self, dictionary):
            self._dictionary = dictionary
        def __setitem__(self, key, item):
                if key not in self._dictionary:
                    raise KeyError("The key {} is not defined.".format(key))
                self._dictionary[key] = item
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            return self._dictionary[key]
```

Also, you should use string formatting instead of `+` to generate the error message, since otherwise it will crash for any value that's not a string.

Answer (score 15):

The problem with direct inheritance from `dict` is that it's quite hard to comply with the full `dict`'s contract (e.g. in your case, `update` method won't behave in a consistent way).

What you want, is to extend the [`collections.MutableMapping`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes):

```
import collections

class FixedDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.__data = data

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__data)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__data)

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        if k not in self.__data:
            raise KeyError(k)

        self.__data[k] = v

    def __delitem__(self, k):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.__data[k]

    def __contains__(self, k):
        return k in self.__data
```

Note that the original (wrapped) dict will be modified, if you don't want that to happen, use [`copy` or `deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

Answer (score 3):

How you prevent someone from adding new keys depends entirely on why someone might try to add new keys.  As the comments state, most dictionary methods that modify the keys don't go through `__setitem__`, so a `.update()` call will add new keys just fine.

If you only expect someone to use `d[new_key] = v`, then your `__setitem__` is fine.  If they might use other ways to add keys, then you have to put in more work.  And of course, they can always use this to do it anyway:

```
dict.__setitem__(d, new_key, v)
```

You can't make things truly immutable in Python, you can only stop particular changes.