# Creating dict-like object whose values can be modified, but whose keys cannot in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I want to create an object that behaves like a `dict` object, whose values can be accessed and modified via keys (like a dictionary would), but whose keys cannot be modified.

What I have right now is something like

```
class Result(dict):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self['a'] = a
        self['b'] = b
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
x = Result(5, 4)
x['a'] = 15 #Allows modification of values
x['c'] = 42 #Raises an error because key 'c' doesn't exist
```

I don't know which methods inherited from `dict` I would need to modify in order to achieve this behaviour. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: cannot reproduce. It works, because `Result` is a `dict`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what do you mean? there is no reproduction, they are asking how they can implement the desired behavior

Comment: Since I can't answer the question anymore, @rmoreno, look into the \_\_setitem\_\_ magic method. You can override that method to called super().__setitem__() only if the key is in the dictionary.

Comment: @potapeno wait a few minutes, it should be reopened soon, then you can answer properly.

Comment: @rmoreno The way your code is written now, an instance of `Result` will only have 2 keys, `a` and `b`. Is that what you want, or can arbitrary keys (with arbitrary names) be assigned at instantiation?

Comment: @MattDMo I would like to have some set keys, which are defined in the ```class``` definition. They are not ```'a'``` and ```'b'```, but they serve as examples. The thing is that I want *only these* keys to exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816341/define-a-python-dictionary-with-immutable-keys-but-mutable-values

Comment: @potapeno I'm guessing that you mean modifying the ```__setitem__``` method so that it only works with pre-existing keys? To have it check if the key exists, and raise an error if it doesn't?

Comment: @MattDMo yeah. It actually is pretty close to what I thought after reading potapeno's suggestion. Thank you very much, and sorry for the repeat-question.

Comment: No worries. One thing to keep in mind when looking at the answers there is that if you don't derive your class from `dict`, you won't have access to methods like `.keys()` and so forth. So it's a complex problem.

Comment: @MattDMo Inheriting from `collections.abc.MutableMapping` solves that problem. As long as you implement the required magic methods, you'll get conveniences like `keys` for free. (And if you forget a method, you'll get an exception as soon as you try to instantiate the class.)